# How to recognize Install from Google Ad Campaign in iOS App to display specific content

Tags: ios, swift, google-analytics, attribution, google-ads-api

we market our App via App Install campaigns via Google Ads. Now we would like to be able to detect within our iOS (and later Android) app that a user is coming from a certain ad campaign, so we can display related content (e.g. a coupon code for all those coming from Google Ad). However, here we are faced with the challenge to recognize within the app after the installation whether the user comes from that Google Ad campaign. We have integrated the Firbase SDK, but I have not found any references here. A Campaign Link from Apple only provides the install in App Analytics, but I cannot access it in the app. What I had found so far was the following documentation:
https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/ios/v3/campaigns
and some tips on how to track the campaign via GAITracker.
However, this refers to the outdated Google Analytics SDK and I have already migrated to Firebase anyway. 
We set up a campaign as follows:
[image]

If a user now sees the advertisement and clicks on it, he will be directed to the App Store via the Google Analytics link *"click.google-analytics....redirect=... "*.
Afterwards I would like to see in the AppDelegate if it comes over such a link. Can I take this from the URL, for example? Or is that not possible because it is routed through the App Store?

```swift
    func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplication.OpenURLOptionsKey: Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

        // Get CampaignName or some identifier from the Google Ad

        return true
    }
```

If this is not possible, would using an attribution service like [Adjust](https://www.adjust.com) or [Branch.io](https://branch.io) be the solution to make this possible? What would be the flow when using such a service?

Many thanks in advance for appropriate help!

Comment: Did you have got a solution?